# Should "get back to the old times" be taken literally or figuratively?

Tags: idiomatic-language

When we say "get back to the old times" it sounds like we mean go back in time with a time machine, but often it seems to be used figuratively? Is it one or the other, or something else (neither figurative or literal)? And when can we use it? I feel it means "be how we used to be", but I am not 100% sure, because it's not really an idiom, but an expression that's often used in casual speak.

Comment: I don’t know how we can take it literally, given that there aren’t any literal time machines.

Comment: You could take it literally if you don't really think hard about it. Anyway, what is the meaning of the phrase and is it commonly used, how idiomatic it is? I feel it's one of these non-sensical phrases that are commonly used, but will never become idiomatic, because of how non-sensical they are.

Comment: I've never heard that exact set of words. Usually that idea is expressed as getting back to  [the way we were](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBPQT2Ia8fU)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Get back to the old times"* does not sound natural to me, but either way it would be meant to be taken *figuratively*, as in we need to get back to *how things used to be*.

> "We need to **get back to a time** when life was simpler, when people knew how to treat each other with respect!" the old man grumbled from his front porch.

If you literally mean to travel to the past through a time machine, then the expression would be "go back *in* time" or a similar expression:

> The classic 80s movie "Back to the Future" is about a teenage boy who **travels back through time** to save his parents' relationship, when they were also teenagers.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I knew it didn't sound idiomatic.